# MVC Model Setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am using pure ado.net for data access. I want to know best practice to do the following.

I have a Generic Product Class....

```
Class ProductViewModel

 Property ItemID as int
 Property Title as string
 ' etc, all other properties.......

End Class
```

Then I have Orders Class

```
Class OrdersViewModel

 Public OrderNumber as string
 Public ShipToAddress as string
 ' etc all properties

End Class
```

I have like 10 other generic classes to be used as ViewModel.

My Question is for every generic class, i need to pull data within my VIEW's....for example GetProductID() Function will return ProductID, GetOrderID will return **OrderID**. **in which class should I perform the actual data access operations?**

How Should I structure my classes, so i can make my life easier to access data within views.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in which class should I perform the data access

Neither, you would generally add a layer of abstraction between your views/data access and pull anything related to the backend from there e.g.

```
Class ProductRepository

Function GetById(ByVal Id As Integer) As Product
    ' Pull product from DB 
End Function

End Class
```

This is known as the [Repository Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). Once you have your repositories you can pull the data from the backend & populate your view models at controller level before passing to the view e.g.

```
Public Class ProductsController Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

Function Index(ByVal Id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim repo As New ProductRepository()
    ' pull product from DB 
    Dim p As Product = repo.GetById(Id)
    ' populate view model
    Dim model As New ProductViewModel()
    model.ItemID = p.ItemID
    model.Title = p.Title
    ...
    ' pass to view
    Return View(model)
End Function

End Class
```

Populating view models in this manner can get quite tedious, especially if you have *loads*, I tend to let tools like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) do it for me.

Comment: what if i make my repo.GetById(Id) to return type ProductViewModel? this way i dont have to create a new instance of ProductViewModel...your thoughts?

Comment: @highwingers no because that's you beginning to couple your view with your data access again. The purpose of the repository is to provide a layer of abstraction between your data access and your business layer - it wouldn't make sense for your repository to return "view" models.

Comment: In my example above I named my product business class to productviewmodel which only exposes properties. I will create ProductRepositary class now for data access. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: @James But it does makes sense for a repo to return view models, the ProductViewsRepository returns 'business' objects as in non data access objects. The view model is the 'business' object for the UI. The purpose of the repo is to abstract persistence, the business layer is not the only layer needing that. I know that Fowler's definition targeted only the busines layer but I don't see why it can't be used for other layers too if it simplifies things.

Comment: @highwingers you would generally have a clear split. A `Product` class which is your data access class (aka business object) and contains *all* the data associated with a product in your system. Then you have your `ProductViewModel` class which contains *only* the data needed for your view.

Comment: @MikeSW A repository should *never* return view models, no matter how you try justify it. It should return a *business* object (aka DTO/POCO). Whose to say your repo will only be used for the purpose of creating view models? It could be used in various parts of your application therefore having it return view models is *wrong*, view models are tailored for specific views therefore can't possibly be generic enough to support all scenarios where you need to pull a product from the repo - even if they were, it still wouldn't be correct.

Comment: Yeah, never. Look, my repositories have precised purpose and they simply can't be used to create new view models. The ProductViewRepository handles only queries and GetViewModel(Criteria) can't create anything. Oh don't tell me you're using generic repositories, the great anti pattern or one repo to rull'em all. I don't need generic stuff, I have context related repositories. I'm using a concept, not bowing to a recipe. These are query specific repositories, not one repo for all the purposes and intentions. It' called CQRS and it's a great concept to simplify things.

Comment: So what you saying is...A Product Class (Business Object, with all properties), A ProductViewModel (Which will expose the properties which I would want to show on my VIEW page), and then an ProductRepository Class(For Data Access From SQL Server)....and then repeat the process for Order Class etc. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @highwingers yep, this ensures there is no coupling between your layers and ensures each class has a single responsibility i.e. ProductRepository should only deal with Products, OrderRepository should only deal with orders and so on....more commonly known as the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: that definitely makes sense & I like it....in some cases my Product Class and ProductViewModel Class would have exact same # of members/properties, So I was thinking i was duplicating classes.

Comment: @highwingers it's quite common to have duplicate information across models/view models, you could even derive your `ProductViewModel` from your `Product` model if you find it has all the same properties. I generally find that my views need less information than what my model has...

Comment: what if my Repo is returning a List(Of product), then how would I assign that to the model.

Comment: @highwingers then you would iterate the list and build a list of view models, like I said you should really look at AutoMapper, it's great for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. class called OrderRepository where you do all the data access to database
2. class called OrderService where you do all your business rules
3. Controller can only call OrderService class and not OrderRepository class.
4. Controller should return the ViewModel to the view

Hope this helps

Comment: so if you were to explain with some dummy classes code how would that work? sorry I am new to MVC.